Package lua-ul: Marginal notes are (only) partially colored
I'm commenting a LaTeX file using the highlight command from the very nice lua-ul package. There is a strange side effect: the coloring in my margin notes is only partially.
MWE:
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{lua-ul}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{luacolor}
\usepackage{ragged2e, setspace}

\newcounter{Rnnr}
\usepackage{perpage, marginfix}
\MakePerPage{Rnnr}% 
\renewcommand{\theRnnr}{\alph{Rnnr}}
\newcommand{\Anm}[1]{%
   %
  \stepcounter{Rnnr}
  \textsuperscript{\textit{\theRnnr}}
  \marginpar{% 
    \RaggedRight\singlespace% 
    \textsuperscript{\theRnnr}% 
    \footnotesize% 
    #1}}%


\begin{document}

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo
ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis
dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis,
ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium quis, sem. Nulla consequat massa
quis enim. Donec pede justo, fringilla vel, aliquet nec, vulputate eget,
arcu. In enim justo, rhoncus ut, imperdiet a, venenatis vitae,
justo. Nullam dictum felis eu pede mollis pretium. Integer
tincidunt. Cras dapibus. Vivamus elementum semper nisi. Aenean vulputate
eleifend tellus. Aenean leo ligula, porttitor eu, consequat vitae,
eleifend ac, enim. \highLight{Aliquam lorem ante, dapibus in, viverra
  quis, feugiat\Anm{One yellow line. But the next lines come without
    highlighting.}  a, tellus.} Phasellus viverra nulla ut metus varius
laoreet. Quisque rutrum. Aenean imperdiet. Etiam ultricies nisi vel
augue. Curabitur ullamcorper ultricies nisi. Nam eget dui. Etiam
rhoncus. Maecenas tempus, tellus eget condimentum rhoncus, sem quam
semper libero, sit amet adipiscing sem neque sed ipsum. Nam quam nunc,
blandit vel, luctus pulvinar, hendrerit id, lorem. Maecenas nec odio et
ante tincidunt tempus. Donec vitae sapien ut libero venenatis
faucibus. Nullam quis ante. Etiam sit amet orci eget eros faucibus
tincidunt. Duis leo. Sed fringilla mauris sit amet nibh. Donec sodales
sagittis magna. Sed consequat, leo eget bibendum sodales, augue velit
cursus nunc,

\end{document}

Result (texlive 24):

If I had a choice, I'd like to know how to avoid any highlighting in the marginal note. And maybe avoid that the printout of the note is one line lower than the anchor in the main text.

You can use package scrlayer-notecolumn:
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{lua-ul}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{luacolor}
\usepackage{ragged2e, setspace}
\usepackage{scrlayer-notecolumn}
\usepackage{scrlayer-scrpage}
\pagestyle{plain}

\newcounter{Rnnr}
\usepackage{perpage, marginfix}
\MakePerPage{Rnnr}% 
\renewcommand{\theRnnr}{\alph{Rnnr}}%
\newcommand{\Anm}[1]{%
  \stepcounter{Rnnr}%
  \textsuperscript{\textit{\theRnnr}}
  \makenote{% 
    \RaggedRight\protect\singlespace% 
    \textsuperscript{\theRnnr}% 
    \footnotesize% 
    #1}}%


\begin{document}

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo
ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis
dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis,
ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium quis, sem. Nulla consequat massa
quis enim. Donec pede justo, fringilla vel, aliquet nec, vulputate eget,
arcu. In enim justo, rhoncus ut, imperdiet a, venenatis vitae,
justo. Nullam dictum felis eu pede mollis pretium. Integer
tincidunt. Cras dapibus. Vivamus elementum semper nisi. Aenean vulputate
eleifend tellus. Aenean leo ligula, porttitor eu, consequat vitae,
eleifend ac, enim. \highLight{Aliquam lorem ante, dapibus in, viverra
  quis, feugiat\Anm{One yellow line. But the next lines come without
    highlighting.}  a, tellus.} Phasellus viverra nulla ut metus varius
laoreet. Quisque rutrum. Aenean imperdiet. Etiam ultricies nisi vel
augue. Curabitur ullamcorper ultricies nisi. Nam eget dui. Etiam
rhoncus. Maecenas tempus, tellus eget condimentum rhoncus, sem quam
semper libero, sit amet adipiscing sem neque sed ipsum. Nam quam nunc,
blandit vel, luctus pulvinar, hendrerit id, lorem. Maecenas nec odio et
ante tincidunt tempus. Donec\Anm{with \highLight{highlight} in note instead
  of text} vitae sapien ut libero venenatis
faucibus. Nullam quis ante. Etiam sit amet orci eget eros faucibus
tincidunt. Duis leo. Sed fringilla mauris sit amet nibh. Donec sodales
sagittis magna. Sed consequat, leo eget bibendum sodales, augue velit
cursus nunc,

\end{document}


AFAIK, with LuaLaTeX it uses its own color stack for the note columns. So the color context of the text area is ignored inside the notes. And as shown in the second note, even highlighting in the note does work.
But, because the \theRnnr has to be expanded, when writing the slnc file, you cannot use the star variant \makenote* in this case and therefore need to protect some commands like \singlespace.
BTW: You don't need to use scrlayer-scrpage. You just need to use a page style of package scrlayer. So, if you, e.g., already use fancyhdr, you could replace fancyhdr by scrlayer-fancyhdr:
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{lua-ul}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{luacolor}
\usepackage{ragged2e, setspace}
\usepackage{scrlayer-notecolumn}
\usepackage{scrlayer-fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}

\newcounter{Rnnr}
\usepackage{perpage, marginfix}
\MakePerPage{Rnnr}% 
\renewcommand{\theRnnr}{\alph{Rnnr}}%
\newcommand{\Anm}[1]{%
  \stepcounter{Rnnr}%
  \textsuperscript{\textit{\theRnnr}}
  \makenote{% 
    \RaggedRight\protect\singlespace% 
    \textsuperscript{\theRnnr}% 
    \footnotesize% 
    #1}}%


\begin{document}

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo
ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis
dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis,
ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium quis, sem. Nulla consequat massa
quis enim. Donec pede justo, fringilla vel, aliquet nec, vulputate eget,
arcu. In enim justo, rhoncus ut, imperdiet a, venenatis vitae,
justo. Nullam dictum felis eu pede mollis pretium. Integer
tincidunt. Cras dapibus. Vivamus elementum semper nisi. Aenean vulputate
eleifend tellus. Aenean leo ligula, porttitor eu, consequat vitae,
eleifend ac, enim. \highLight{Aliquam lorem ante, dapibus in, viverra
  quis, feugiat\Anm{One yellow line. But the next lines come without
    highlighting.}  a, tellus.} Phasellus viverra nulla ut metus varius
laoreet. Quisque rutrum. Aenean imperdiet. Etiam ultricies nisi vel
augue. Curabitur ullamcorper ultricies nisi. Nam eget dui. Etiam
rhoncus. Maecenas tempus, tellus eget condimentum rhoncus, sem quam
semper libero, sit amet adipiscing sem neque sed ipsum. Nam quam nunc,
blandit vel, luctus pulvinar, hendrerit id, lorem. Maecenas nec odio et
ante tincidunt tempus. Donec\Anm{with \highLight{highlight} in note instead
  of text} vitae sapien ut libero venenatis
faucibus. Nullam quis ante. Etiam sit amet orci eget eros faucibus
tincidunt. Duis leo. Sed fringilla mauris sit amet nibh. Donec sodales
sagittis magna. Sed consequat, leo eget bibendum sodales, augue velit
cursus nunc,

\end{document}


Hey, thank you. scrlayer-notecolumn lacks a feature of the marginfix package: marginfix avoids automatically collisions, as far as I know, and if the text in the last margin is long, marginfix shifts all marginnotes vertically.

scrlayer-notecolumn also avoids collisions, but by supporting page breaks in notes. So if notes do not fit to a page it automatically continues the notes on the next page. Maybe you've mixed with marginnote?

@KeksDose However, I've overseen the usage of \theRnnr in the note, so you would not be able to use \makenote*. And with \makenote it is a very ugly.

I haven't found the explanation for the starred version in the manual, but in my file with many margin notes per page, it did not work.

@KeksDose See the changed answer. In scrguide-de.pdf of KOMA-Script 3.41 you can find \makenote* at page 496.

I tested both versions: marginpar with marginfix or scrlayer-notecolumn. The latter is really slower and scrlayer-notecolumn tends to print a note on the next pages margin, while marginfix simply uses the bottom of the page. By the way, I still don't find any explanation about the difference between \makenote with and without star, exactly on p. 496. Seems I'm blind, sigh.

@KeksDose Have you seen this passage: https://i.imgur.com/dTlpIlP.png

Ah, no, I haven't. Thank you. OK, I use references inside my marginal notes.

References shouldn't be a general problem. But depending on the packages and commands you are using \protect could be needed. And if you are using footnotes for the references, this could indeed be a problem.

@KeksDose However, the author AFAIK states, that the package is only experimental. So I do absolutely understand if someone likes every other solution more than using this package. Actually, I was just curious whether the package would prevent the color problem from the outset. When it did, I showed the result.

Both answers are workarounds. I hope that someone confirms this to be a bug of lua-ul or another package and I'll happily file a bug report.

Quick hack: put a white highlight on top.
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{lua-ul}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{luacolor}
\usepackage{ragged2e, setspace}

\newcounter{Rnnr}
\usepackage{perpage, marginfix}
\MakePerPage{Rnnr}% 
\renewcommand{\theRnnr}{\alph{Rnnr}}
\newcommand{\Anm}[1]{%
  \LuaULSetHighLightColor{white}%
  \stepcounter{Rnnr}%
  \textsuperscript{\textit{\theRnnr}}%
  \highLight{\marginpar{% 
    \RaggedRight\singlespace% 
    \textsuperscript{\theRnnr}% 
    \footnotesize% 
    #1}}}%

\begin{document}

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo
ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis
dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis,
ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium quis, sem. Nulla consequat massa
quis enim. Donec pede justo, fringilla vel, aliquet nec, vulputate eget,
arcu. In enim justo, rhoncus ut, imperdiet a, venenatis vitae,
justo. Nullam dictum felis eu pede mollis pretium. Integer
tincidunt. Cras dapibus. Vivamus elementum semper nisi. Aenean vulputate
eleifend tellus. Aenean leo ligula, porttitor eu, consequat vitae,
eleifend ac, enim. \highLight{Aliquam lorem ante, dapibus in, viverra
  quis, feugiat\Anm{One yellow line. But the next lines come without
    highlighting.}  a, tellus.} Phasellus viverra nulla ut metus varius
laoreet. Quisque rutrum. Aenean imperdiet. Etiam ultricies nisi vel
augue. Curabitur ullamcorper ultricies nisi. Nam eget dui. Etiam
rhoncus. Maecenas tempus, tellus eget condimentum rhoncus, sem quam
semper libero, sit amet adipiscing sem neque sed ipsum. Nam quam nunc,
blandit vel, luctus pulvinar, hendrerit id, lorem. Maecenas nec odio et
ante tincidunt tempus. Donec vitae sapien ut libero venenatis
faucibus. Nullam quis ante. Etiam sit amet orci eget eros faucibus
tincidunt. \highLight{Duis leo.} Sed fringilla mauris sit amet nibh. Donec sodales
sagittis magna. Sed consequat, leo eget bibendum sodales, augue velit
cursus nunc,

\end{document}



For the vertical position of the marginnote the hack gets rather ugly: add some negative vertical space. But: the offset is bigger when you are in a highlight. So: add a check if you are in the highlight or not by hooking into \highLight and conditionally adjust the shift.
Also you need to reset the color to yellow at the end of \Anm if the marginnotes are ever used outside, as I found out.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lua-ul}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{luacolor}
\usepackage{ragged2e, setspace}
\newif\ifinhl
\inhlfalse
\AddToHook{cmd/highLight/before}{\inhltrue}
\AddToHook{cmd/highLight/after}{\inhlfalse}
\def\shiftup{0mm}
\newcounter{Rnnr}
\usepackage{perpage, marginfix}
\MakePerPage{Rnnr}% 
\renewcommand{\theRnnr}{\alph{Rnnr}}
\newcommand{\Anm}[1]{%
  \LuaULSetHighLightColor{white}%
  \stepcounter{Rnnr}%
  \ifinhl\gdef\shiftup{-9mm}\else\gdef\shiftup{-5mm}\fi
  \textsuperscript{\textit{\theRnnr}}%
  \highLight{\marginpar{% 
    \RaggedRight\singlespace% 
    \vspace{\shiftup}\textsuperscript{\theRnnr}% 
    \footnotesize% 
    #1}}%
    \LuaULSetHighLightColor{yellow}}%

\begin{document}

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit\Anm{marginnote outside of highlighting}. Aenean commodo
ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis
dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis,
ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium quis, sem. Nulla consequat massa
quis enim. Donec pede justo, fringilla vel, aliquet nec, vulputate eget,
arcu. In enim justo, rhoncus ut, imperdiet a, venenatis vitae,
justo. Nullam dictum felis eu pede mollis pretium. Integer
tincidunt. Cras dapibus. Vivamus elementum semper nisi. Aenean vulputate
eleifend tellus. Aenean leo ligula, porttitor eu, consequat vitae,
eleifend ac, enim. \highLight{Aliquam lorem ante, dapibus in, viverra
  quis, feugiat\Anm{One yellow line. But the next lines come without
    highlighting.}  a, tellus.} Phasellus viverra nulla ut metus varius
laoreet. Quisque rutrum. Aenean imperdiet. Etiam ultricies nisi vel
augue. Curabitur ullamcorper ultricies nisi. Nam eget dui. Etiam
rhoncus. Maecenas tempus, tellus eget condimentum rhoncus, sem quam
semper libero, sit amet adipiscing sem neque sed ipsum. Nam quam nunc,
blandit vel, luctus pulvinar, hendrerit id, lorem. Maecenas nec odio et
ante tincidunt tempus. Donec vitae sapien ut libero venenatis
faucibus. Nullam quis ante. Etiam sit amet orci eget eros faucibus
tincidunt. \highLight{Duis leo.} Sed fringilla mauris sit amet nibh. Donec sodales
sagittis magna. Sed consequat, leo eget bibendum sodales, augue velit
cursus nunc,

\end{document}



Very pragmatic approach! Thank you. The margin note still is one line lower than without any highlighting (neither in the text, nor in the margin).

@KeksDose see edit - it doesn't look very robust though, so if you actually want to use this then check carefully if the result is what you want.

Yes, found out about the need to use \LuaULSetHighLightColor{yellow} myself: text looked so peacefully...
